# io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/owasp/esapi/errors/EncodingException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netty, noclassdeffounderror, esapi

Details of my application:

Microservice - Spring boot 1.3.5.RELEASE, JDK 8

Application - Spring framework 5.3.15, JDK 8

Functionality: I am uploading an excel file in my application that uses the above microservice to process it further. This functionality was working well when my application was on spring 4.2.1.RELEASE.

Error:

```
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/owasp/esapi/errors/EncodingException
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:278) ~[netty-all-4.0.24.Final.jar:4.0.24.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:147) ~[netty-all-4.0.24.Final.jar:4.0.24.Final]
```

I upgraded the esapi library to the latest but still it giving me the same error.

What could be possible reasons for this issue? How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you miss the dependency `esapi`, which contains the missing class, in your project. If you use maven, add

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.owasp.esapi/esapi -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
    <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

to yout dependencies in your pom.xml

Comment: I already have that in my pom.xml file. I am able to build my project successfully. This is the runtime error I am getting

Comment: What is the scope of that dependency

Comment: default scope - compile